# Using two arrays for output

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox, selectedindex

I am trying to figure out how to output results based on a selection in a listbox object. Like if I select "2002", I want it to output the total rainfall for that year. I've tried researching through stack and google and I can't seem to find anything unless I am explaining it incorrectly. I want the arrays to output based on their indexes. Here's the necessary code.

```
Public Class frmRainfall

    ' Class level Variables

    Dim strYearSelection() As String = {
        "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009",
        "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"
    }

    Dim strYear As String

    ' Yearly stats found online due to issues finding text file

    Dim decYearlyRainfallTotals() As Decimal = {

        28.66, 37.56, 31.36, 41.78, 31.1, 35.44, 48.82, 38.95, 30.73, 38.44, 46.99,
        36.39, 48.26, 32.56, 48.5, 44.83, 45.18, 47.87
    }

    Dim intOneYearTotal As Integer
    Dim intOverallTotal As Integer
    Dim intAverage As Integer

    Private Sub frmRainfall_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'The Form at load will read the text file (Unavailable, read comment
        ' at the end of the frmRainfall sub procedure) and fill the ListBox object with the
        'Year items.

        For Each strYear In strYearSelection
            lstSelectYear.Items.Add(strYear)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what you want

First, gets you the selected year

```
Dim selectedYr as String = Convert.ToString(lstSelectYear.Text)
```

Gets the index of the selected year and the precip in that index.

```
Dim precip as Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(decYearlyRainfallTotals(Array.IndexOf(strYearSelection, selectedYr)))
```

I'd like to recommend a different data structure.  A dictionary of key value pairs.  It gives you a relationship between your months and precip amounts.

```
Dim dict as new Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

Adding a record:

```
dict.Add("2000", 28.66)
```

Getting all the years

```
Dim allYears() as String = dict.Keys.ToArray()
```

Getting a year's value

```
Dim value as String = dict("2000")
```

Comment: changed year data type to string

Comment: When i tried adding the first two lines, I get an IndexOutOfRange Exception somehow

Comment: It shows it in the 2nd line with the Dim precip As Decimal declaration line

Comment: try Convert.ToString(lstSelectYear.Text) instead of SelectedValue...its based on your dropdownlist style

Comment: I just selected 2 random ones from the listbox and the program crashes and shows that whole line as out of bounds

Comment: try my next recommendation...i changed the code...Dim selectedYr as String = Convert.ToString(lstSelectYear.Text)

Comment: I did that and nothing changes when I push the button.

Comment: actually wait let me try something

Comment: Upvoted and starred good sir, I forgot to set the text in the label. Everything is good after the edit you told me. Thanks

Comment: super to hear that

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On`

Comment: @codexer I forgot the convert.todecimal piece...added